# Define add_editor_style to specific post types?

Tags: visual-editor, post-type, add-editor-style

I am wondering is it posible to define add_editor_style to specific post types?

Currently I am using this function..

```
// EDITOR STYLE
add_editor_style('editor-style.css');
```

But I would like have multiple editor styles for various post types.

So guessing it could be like this...

```
if ( ... ) {

// EDITOR STYLE POSTS & PAGES
add_editor_style('editor-style.css');

} else if ( ... ) {

// EDITOR STYLE CUSTOM POST-TYPE BOOKS
add_editor_style('editor-style-books.css');

}
```

My post types are `page`, `post`, `book`

Any ideas would be great thanks

Comment: Maybe if used in combination with admin_print_styles-(post-hook) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is that `add_editor_style()` is usually called in Theme setup functions that get hooked into `after_setup_theme` - which is well before the query is set up and the post type determined. So, you'll need to move `add_editor_style()` to a separate callback, that gets called *after* the query is setup, but *before* TinyMCE is initialized. Perhaps `tiny_mce_before_init`?

```
<?php
function wpse59547_add_editor_style() {
    global $post;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    $editor_style = 'editor-style-' . $post_type . '.css';
    add_editor_style( $editor_style );
}
add_action( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse59547_add_editor_style' );
```

Then, you just need to create `editor-style-post.css`, `editor-style-book.css`, etc.

If you want to default to `editor-style.css`, use [`get_post_types( array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ) )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) to return an array of custom post types, and use that, e.g.:

```
$custom_post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ) );
$editor_style = ( in_array( $post_type, $custom_post_types ) ? 'editor-style-' . $post_type . '.css' : 'editor-style.css' );
```

Comment: Nice one chip, this was just what I was after. Very big thanks! Josh

Comment: I would rather use **editor_stylesheets** filter